# How can I send e-mails to trac?

Tags: project-management, trac, email, issue-tracking

How would I send an e-mail message to a trac project?

I like this feature in basecamp, where each project has its e-mail address, and received mails are added in the messages tab.

In redmine I can even send e-mails to specific tickets.

Is there something similar in trac, or maybe a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the plugin [email2trac](https://subtrac.sara.nl/oss/email2trac), but I have not used it. There was a [ticket](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/250) to add this feature to Trac, but because of the existence of the plugin it was closed as wontfix. Someone does complain that email2trac is not user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

[link text](https://subtrac.sara.nl/oss/email2trac) is the standard. It does require a little setting up but the default config is a good place to start.